# PHP: trim() doesn't work with two variables

Tags: php, error-handling, trim

Alright, guys, so it is either there is some minor issue I don't catch or it's just time to sleep. Whatever it is, I would highly appreciate your advice.

I am generating an XML file with PHP. Everything worked smoothly till the moment I input this line:

```
$out .= "<name>" . trim($prod["name"], $prod["model"]) . "</name>";
```

and so an error occurred (logs below).

Everything works nicely if one of the variables is changed into the pure string. Say, both of these work perfectly:

```
$out .= "<name>" . trim($prod["name"], "123") . "</name>";
$out .= "<name>" . trim("123", $prod["model"]) . "</name>";
```

Here is what logs say:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !

mod_fcgid: stderr: Bytes: 0x9A 0xD0 0xB5 0xD0 in /xml/file.phpon line 193

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): picture&gt;&lt;vendor&gt;VES electric&lt;/vendor&gt;&lt;stock_quantity&gt;1000&lt;/stock_quantity&gt;&lt;name&gt; in /xml/file.php on line 193

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  SimpleXMLElement::__construct():                                                                                ^ in /xml/file.php on line 193

mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in /xml/file.php:193

mod_fcgid: stderr: Stack trace:

mod_fcgid: stderr: #0 /xml/rozetka.php(193): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<?xml version="...')

mod_fcgid: stderr: #1 {main}

mod_fcgid: stderr:   thrown in /xml/file.php on line 193
```

Thanks again for your help.

Comment: As far as I can see, the `trim()`-function isn't throwing any errors? Check what `$out` actually contains after using the trim. Just to make sure, you're trying to trim away the chars  in `$prod['model']` from `$prod['name']`? Since the second argument is what you actually should trim away.

Comment: are you sure that you understand what 2nd argument to trim does?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson 2nd argument is char mask, so all symbols which appear in model, will be trimmed from name

Comment: @IłyaBursov - I know. I'm asking the OP if that's the intention.

Comment: Yes, I know what it does. Here is the situation: 
There are products with names like "product abc1" where "abc1" is a duplicate of a model information. Don't ask me how this happened. And "abc1" should be deleted

Comment: @VladB. then you should not use trim, but str_replace, because `trim('product pabc1', 'pabc1')` will return `roduct`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, exactly. As described above.

Comment: Just as @IłyaBursov pointed out, you shouldn't use `trim()` for this since it will trim away _any_ of the characters in the second argument, not just the complete string. Here's an example: https://3v4l.org/KHLUO

Comment: @IłyaBursov, thank you. Your approach did work.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, it worked, yes. Thank you for your help. A bit of hellish example, heh

Answer (score 0):

As @IłyaBursov and @MagnusEriksson pointed out, I had to use str_replace() instead of trim(). 
Thanks for your help, guys!